# Randomly got the "Get a tour of your new Macbook Air" on a 6 year old Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur, apple-silicon

I was playing a game and out of the blue, I got a notification saying "Take a tour of your new Macbook Air." and when clicking it, it took me to [the tour page](https://help.apple.com/macos/big-sur/macbook-air/?lang=en&cases=kIFAGHvXTAepRptQXiXe5w,N0bfKOvERSiAp06mHOcgOQ) in Safari. The weird thing is that this Mac wasn't factory reset recently, and is a 6-year-old Macbook Pro. On the website, it said that it was a Mac with an M1 Chip. I think it may be because Somebody in my family bought a Macbook Air recently, but it's not an M1 Mac. I'm not looking for a solution, but I'm just wondering if anybody knows why this happened or if this has happened to anybody else..

Comment: I had this too just now. I'm on an Intel MacBook Pro.  :P

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen before, though not in identical circumstances.

Something has raised a flag, which you need to clear.

Clear it by taking the tour, even if you cancel out of it halfway through.
Flag gone.

Comment: That's what I did and it's gone, but I'm just wondering if anybody knows what flag was raised or why it even happened.